# faker python - set custom word list for faker.word()

Tags: python, faker

I have followed the basic explanation of using faker from geeksforgeeks and tried to reproduce application 5:

```
import faker from Faker 
fake = Faker() 
# Print random sentences 
print(fake.sentence()) 

# List has words that we want in our sentence 
word_list = ["GFG", "Geeksforgeeks", "shaurya", "says", "Gfg", "GEEKS"] 

# Let's print 5 sentences that have words from our word_list  
for i in range(0, 5): 

    # You need to use ext_word_list = listnameyoucreated  
    print(fake.sentence(ext_word_list = word_list))
```

When compiling this code this error occurs:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 13, in 
>       print(fake.sentence(ext_word_list = word_list))
>
> TypeError: sentence() got an unexpected keyword argument
>   'ext_word_list'

I have found the following problem occurs when trying to make the function fake.word() use my preset array of strings. I have also thoroughly read the faker documentation, namely the *faker.providers.lorem* section, from where these functions originate, but to no avail.

Comment: Works fine for me when you do `from faker import Faker`. Are you sure you're using a current version of the module? Try running the following: `pip3 install --upgrade faker` (or whatever your pip executable is called).

Comment: I have executed `pip3 install --upgrade faker` , but now i get a new error, *nb_words = self.randomize_nb_elements(nb_words, min=1)

TypeError: randomize_nb_elements() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min'*

Comment: Which version of python are you using? I tried with 2.7 and 3.7.

Comment: I am using Python version 3.7.2 and faker version 1.0.4

Comment: Same here on all accounts. What happens if you do something like `Faker().sentence(6, True, ["a", "b", "c"])`? And check that it's using the provider you think it is: `>>> Faker().sentence
<bound method Provider.sentence of <faker.providers.lorem.en_US.Provider object at 0x10ca59550>>`

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `import faker from Faker`

Python3 will definitely throw an error.

Instead, use `from faker import Faker`.

After changes, your code will run perfectly in my system.

### Vesions

1. python==3.10.12
2. faker==19.13.0